# Vim seamless file split with same features over the split windows

Tags: split

I have been searching for a way to do the following but haven't found exactly what I need, not sure if it's possible.
I want to be able to split a file, but have the same features over the two splits as if I was in a single pane. Let me give an example:

- I have a 200 line file, and 80 line column length in my terminal.
- when I split, lines 0-79 should appear in the first pane, and lines 80-159 in the second (possible with `mpage.vim`, as I have tried).
- If I do a page down, the first pane should show lines 160-199, and the second pane should be empty.
- if I'm at the end of the first pane and hit `j`, it should jump to the first line of the next pane.

So basically what I'm looking for is to have a seamless split, but have everything operate as if I was in a single pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something similar to what you want:

```
" Two columns.
" 1. Vertically split window
" 2. Offset it one screen
" 3. Scrollbind
command! TwoColumns
            \   exe "normal! zR"
            \ | set noscrollbind
            \ | vsplit
            \ | set scrollbind
            \ | wincmd w
            \ | exe "normal! \<c-f>2\<C-e>"
            \ | set scrollbind
            \ | wincmd p
```

[image]

Not sure if you also want to change active window when you reach the last line.